# (-1)^n exponentiation in c++

Tags: c++, math, optimization

Consider a convergent serie in the form:

```
sum(((-1)^n)*something)
```

where `n` is the index of iteration (`n` goes from `1` to `infinity`).

If we implement direclty the formula, we have `std::pow(-1, n)` but is there a more "rapid" algorithmic trick to implement that ?

Comment: You can always use a boolean condition if `pow` is too slow.

Comment: Have you benchmarked? How do you know the compiler doesn't automatically optimize away the exponential?

Comment: How is that convergent? Won't the sum flicker between `-something` and `0` as `n` goes from `1` to `infinity`?

Comment: @mattjgalloway I’m sure `something` isn’t a variable here, but just a placeholder for a term that is of no matter for this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check whether `n` is even or odd,

```
(n % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
```

does it. If you want to avoid a branch,

```
1 - 2*(n & 1)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure (n & 1)?-1:1 is the faster method. I'd worry that % 2 makes it actually divide (if n is not unsigned), and multiplication most likely does lead to true multiplication, which is at least a few cycles on a modern processor. gcc at the very least does a good job at sorting out ternary expressions without branching.

Comment: @MatsPetersson If the compiler doesn't replace a `% 2` with an `& 1` (on a two's complement machine), throw it away, it's garbage. The multiplication should only remain one if bit-shifting isn't faster on the platform in question. But I wouldn't expect the branchless code to be faster either. Should both be pretty much the same.

Comment: gcc does a and with one, but adds another 4 instructions to cope with the fact that n may be negative. Make it unsigned [assuming that's valid] and it doesn't. ` movl %edi, %eax
 shrl $31, %eax
 leal (%rdi,%rax), %esi
 andl $1, %esi
 subl %eax, %esi`
(That's probably looking very messy in a comment!)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Oh four-letter-word, it does indeed. The one time I heed the "write `% 2` if you mean to test parity, the compiler will sort it out" exhortations, I shouldn't have, and stuck to instinct.

Comment: It does a pretty decent job of avoiding the 30-something cycle div instruction, but I will ALWAYS use the single cycle "and" over a "cleverly optimised div" any day... I have seen variants of gcc [and other compilers] that actually produce a div instruction, so it could have been worse!

Comment: I just tested in clang as well, and it does a differnet variant, but it still results in several instructions.

Comment: I always use `& 1` too, because to me that's a clearer expression of what I intend. But this time I thought, I'd do what others deem clearer :(

Comment: Still, that makes both Clang and GCC in their current state garbage ;) Given a binary computer as a target, a further irreducible `x % (1 << k)` must always be optimized to `x & ((1 << k) - 1)`, regardless of the constant-ness of `k`.

Comment: @Tinctorius I can't deny that. For replacing the modulo operation on signed integers, of course two's complement is a requirement.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that `sum(((-1)^n)*something)` is pseudocode, and `n` is a variable bound by sum.

Let's extend that notation to `sum(n <- [0,1,2,3..], ((-1)^n)*f(n))`. Your best option would probably be to first split this into two sums, that you add together:

```
sum(n <- [0,2..], ((-1)^n)*f(n)) + sum(n <- [1,3..], ((-1)^n)*f(n))
```

In the first term, `n` is always even, so `(-1)^n` will always be `+1`. Analogously, in the second term, it will always be `-1`. We can now rewrite this as follows:

```
sum(n <- [0,2..], f(n)) + sum(n <- [1,3..], -f(n))
```

Since every term in the second sum is multiplied by a constant, we can move that constant out of the sum:

```
sum(n <- [0,2..], f(n)) - sum(n <- [1,3..], f(n))
```

Now, let's make sure these sums take the same sequences of indices, and substitute `2*m` and `2*m+1` for `n`:

```
sum(m <- [0,1..], f(2*m)) - sum(m <- [0,1..], f(2*m+1))
```

Now we can unite these sums again:

```
sum(m <- [0,1..], f(2*m) - f(2*m+1))
```

Or, if you want pseudo-C:

```
T result = 0;
for(m = 0; m < limit; m+=2) {
    result += f(m);
    result -= f(m+1);
}
```

This saves you a multiplication by `+1` or `-1`, as most seem to suggest here. Since your sequence is convergent, taking an extra term should not negatively influence the correctness of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is a magic trick: `(-1)^n == 1` if and only if `n` is even, and `(-1)^n == -1` if and only if `n` is odd. Thus:

```
int p = (n % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
sum(p*something)
```

Answer (score 1):

The term `((-1)^n)*something` evaluates to `-something` for odd `n`, or `something` for even `n`:

`n & 1 ? -something : something`

If `something` is a constant value, then `sum(((-1)^n)*something)` evaluates to `-something` when the last value of `n` is odd, or `0` for an even number of summands:

`n & 1 ? -something : 0`

In this case, the serie would not be convergent.

Comment: -1 ^n is 1 or -1 depending on n, not 1 or 0 - so -something or +something.

Comment: My interpretatin was that "something" is not a constant.

Comment: My interpretation is that average developers are really bad at maths.

Comment: The term "convergent series" does however imply that it's not a constant something, as that will just oscilate, as you describe, between 0 and -something - that's not convergence in my math book - but that was more about thirty years ago, so maybe "new math" doesn't have the same interpretation of convergence.

Comment: @MatsPetersson LOL, my maths book is probably a bit more recent, but in fact, the serie is not convergent.

Comment: @ft1: It's safe to assume that the OP really meant `f(n)` by `something`. Combined with the guarantee that the series is convergent, the function `f` must either be constantly `0`, or not constant at all.

Comment: Hey @MatsPetersson and ft1, you are both saying the same thing. One is saying that "if something is constant, then the series is not convergent", the other is saying "if the series is convergent, then something is not constant". And (according to my even older math books) these two statements are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ft1: The second part is still *very* incorrect. Why would it suddenly evaluate to `0`? For even `n`, `(-1)^n=1`, so `((-1)^n)*something = 1*something = something`. It doesn't matter how constant `something` is.

Comment: @Tinctorius, the second part is about the *sum* of the terms `((-1)^n)*something`, as asked in the question. This sum is `- something + something - something + something ...`, which is either 0 or `-something`, hence not convergent. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: I see your point, I misread the answer. However, since the question clearly asserts that the series is convergent, you can assume `something` is chosen accordingly (converging to `0` for increasing `n`; which means it could also be constantly `0`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in a loop, you could simply do:

```
x = 1;   // Assuming we start on n = 0
for(...)    // or while(...)
{
   sum += x * something;

   x = -x;
}
```

This is most likely a lot faster than doing checks on n - of course, it DOES assume that all n values are iterated over, and you are not skipping a few here and there...